# Is getting page type/name from selected tab css a feasible idea?

Tags: javascript, css, web, google-analytics, portlet

I have a page with multiple tabs.I need to add google analytics code to the page,but as all tabs are part of same page,and I need to get tab name to have data on which phase is user interacting with.Is using css ,to check for selected tab a feasible idea or do we have other possible options to achieve the same?

Edit:On tab selection the page reloads but the URL remains constant.It is one portlet in which all tabs are present

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely track your tabs with Google Analytics. Here's an article about using Google Analytics on a single-page app:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

You basically just send virtual pageviews for each tab view.

Comment: For me,even the page Url remains same.Updated my question too